# Virtuemart setting "Checkout" link to target="new"

Tags: virtuemart

I know this question is specific to VM only but I have run out of options.
I'm usually ok with minimal php code editing, but his is over my head.

I can not find the php that relates to the "checkout" link

I need to have it open in a new window ie. target="new"

Reason being; VM is running in an iframe (facebook) and for Paypal to work I need to pull the user out of iframe and into new window on checkout.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the checkout link in

```
components/com_virtuemart/themes/default/templates/pages/shop.cart.tpl.php
```

(If you're not using the default theme then replace 'default' with the name of your theme's directory).

You might have had trouble finding the checkout link because VirtueMart uses language files, so the text for the checkout link is actually `PHPSHOP_CHECKOUT_TITLE` and looked up from `administrator/components/com_virtuemart/languages/common/` e.g. `english.php`. The workflow is recursively `grep` for the text to find it in the language file then recursively `grep` for its reference to find where it's used.

The checkout link is generated by a call to vmCommonHTML hyperlink, which takes the following parameters:

```
function hyperLink( $link, $text, $target='', $title='', $attributes='' )
...
```

So you'd need to specify the target in the third parameter, so change:

```
echo vmCommonHTML::hyperlink( $href, $text, '', $text, $class_att );
```

to

```
echo vmCommonHTML::hyperlink( $href, $text, 'new', $text, $class_att );
```